Dynamic parameters for update a row action in Power Automate desktop
I have a problem with action "Update a row" (Excel online business) in PAD. I used variables for filename and table id (file on a Sharepoint site) and it every time new one for each run.
But I have error "Dynamic input schema couldn't be retrieved" and can't type parameters for updating column values.
dynamic values

Error message

If I chose file directly sure I can work. But I need to have dynamic values.
direct values for parameters

I used the get tables action to get Table ID. And use this variable for action update a row. But I cannot run the flow because of error message.
Has anybody had the same issue?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

any luck with this?
